# How to fix this SettingWithCopyWarning with pd.DataFrame.apply()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've a dataframe with 2-columns: ImageData, Label. ImageData column is of 2-D array for various dimensions. Label column is boolean True/False.

I'm trying to convert data in the "ImageData" column to 128x128 shape (along with minor other transformations). So, I'm doing following:

```
def convert_image_to_binary_image(img: np.ndarray, threshold: int = 1, max_value: int = 1) -> np.ndarray:
    ret, bin_img = cv.threshold(img, thresh=threshold, maxval=max_value, type=cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    bin_img = bin_img.astype('float32')
    return bin_img

def transform_img_dimension(img: np.ndarray, target_width: int = 128, target_height: int = 128) -> np.ndarray:
    img = img.astype('uint8')

    bin_image = convert_image_to_binary_image(img)
    bin_3dimg = tf.expand_dims(input=bin_image, axis=2)
    bin_img_reshaped = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image=bin_3dimg, target_width=target_width, target_height=target_height, method="bilinear")

    xformed_img = np.squeeze(bin_img_reshaped, axis=2)

    # return xformed_img.copy()
    return xformed_img
```

I'm calling *apply* as following:

```
testDF["ImageData"] = testDF.apply(lambda row: transform_img_dimension(row["ImageData"], axis=1)
```

But that's causing SettingWithCopyWarning.

I tried defining a wrapper function (instead of lambda) as following:

```
def transform_dimension(row: pd.Series, target_width: int = 128, target_height: int = 128) -> np.ndarray:
    copy_row = row.copy(deep=True)
    xformed_data = transform_img_dimension(copy_row["ImageData"], target_width=target_width, target_height=target_height)
    del copy_row
    return xformed_data
```

And updated the call to *apply* as following:

```
testDF["ImageData"] = testDF.apply(transform_dimension, axis=1)
```

However, this is not resolving the problem. What is the fix for this warning for my case?

### Update 1:

If I rewrite as following, I don't get the warning

```
testDF2 = testDF.copy(deep=True)
testDF2["ImageData"] = testDF.apply(lambda row: transform_img_dimension(row["ImageData"], axis=1)
```

Is it not memory overhead now to hold 2 dataframes? Am I recommended to delete the original dataframe, testDF, now?

Comment: adding .copy before you take the sub df

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: @BENY - do you mean testDF.copy(deep=True).apply()? Otherwise, if I understand correctly, I've attempted copy on *row* in transform_dimension().

Comment: @Tim I tried this : testDF2 = testDF.copy(deep=True) testDF2["ImageData"] = testDF.apply(lambda arr: transform_img_dimension(arr["ImageData"], axis=1)                         this didn't cause the warning. Is it not memory overhead now to hold 2 dataframes? Or did I understand something wrong?